# Type of fun g x = ys where ys = [x] ++ filter (curry g x) ys?

Tags: haskell, types, unification

I'm trying to understand why the type of `fun g x = ys where ys = [x] ++ filter (curry g x) ys` is `((a, a) -> Bool) -> a -> [a]`.

I understand that:

`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` and that `curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c`

But I don't understand how to continue.

Comment: Please put a bit more effort into your question.  E.g. try breaking up your problem into smaller pieces.

Comment: @luqui

Ok, I'm trying but it is not easy for me to understand how to derive types in Haskell.

But for example if I try evaluate take 5 (fun (uncurry (==)) 1).

It's ok to start like this:

fun (uncurry (==)) = \x -> ys where ys = [x] ++ filter (x) ys?

I did that because it a partial evaluation.

Thanks again!

Comment: @Seba look at the expression `curry g`, where `g :: (a1, a1) -> Bool`.  Since `curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c`, if we say that `a1 ~ a`, `a1 ~ b`, and `Bool ~ c`, then `curry g` has the type `a1 -> a1 -> Bool`.  Then we apply a value of type `a1` to it, so `curry g x :: a1 -> Bool`, which fits into the `filter` function quite nicely.  (The `~` sign means type equality).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The approach below is not necessarily the easiest or fastest, but it's relatively systematic.

---

Strictly speaking, you're looking for the type of

```
\g -> (\ x -> let ys = (++) [x] (filter (curry g x) ys) in ys)
```

(`let` and `where` are equivalent, but it's sometimes a little easier to reason using `let`), given the types

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
```

Don't forget that you're also using

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Let's first look at the 'deepest' part of the syntax tree:

```
curry g x
```

We have `g` and `x`, of which we haven't seen before yet, so we'll assume that they have some type:

```
g :: t1
x :: t2
```

We also have `curry`. At every point where these functions occur, the type variables (`a`, `b`, `c`) can be specialized differently, so it's a good idea to replace them with a fresh name every time you use these functions. At this point, `curry` has the following type:

```
curry :: ((a1, b1) -> c1) -> a1 -> b1 -> c1
```

We can then only say `curry g x` if the following types can be unified:

```
t1  ~  ((a1, b1) -> c1)       -- because we apply curry to g
t2  ~  a1                     -- because we apply (curry g) to x
```

It's then also safe to assume that

```
g :: ((a1, b1) -> c1)
x :: a1
---
curry g x :: b1 -> c1
```

Let's continue:

```
filter (curry g x) ys
```

We see `ys` for the first time, so let's keep it at `ys :: t3` for now. We also have to instantiate `filter`. So at this point, we know

```
filter :: (a2 -> Bool) -> [a2] -> [a2]
ys :: t3
```

Now we must match the types of `filter`'s arguments:

```
b1 -> c1  ~  a2 -> Bool
t3        ~  [a2]
```

The first constraint can be broken down to

```
b1  ~  a2
c1  ~  Bool
```

We now know the following:

```
g :: ((a1, a2) -> Bool)
x :: a1
ys :: [a2]
---
filter (curry g x) ys :: [a2]
```

Let's continue.

```
(++) [x] (filter (curry g x) ys)
```

I won't spend too much time on explaining `[x] :: [a1]`, let's see the type of `(++)`:

```
(++) :: [a3] -> [a3] -> [a3]
```

We get the following constraints:

```
[a1]  ~  [a3]           -- [x]
[a2]  ~  [a3]           -- filter (curry g x) ys
```

Since these constraints can be reduced to

```
a1  ~  a3
a2  ~  a2
```

we'll just call all these `a`'s `a1`:

```
g :: ((a1, a1) -> Bool)
x :: a1
ys :: [a1]
---
(++) [x] (filter (curry g x) ys) :: [a1]
```

For now, I'll ignore that `ys`' type gets generalized, and focus on

```
\x -> let { {- ... -} } in ys
```

We know what type we need for `x`, and we know the type of `ys`, so we now know

```
g :: ((a1, a1) -> Bool)
ys :: [a1]
---
(\x -> let { {- ... -} } in ys) :: a1 -> [a1]
```

In a similar fashion, we can conclude that

```
(\g -> (\x -> let { {- ... -} } in ys)) :: ((a1, a1) -> Bool) -> a1 -> [a1]
```

At this point, you only have to rename (actually, generalize, because you want to bind it to `fun`) the type variables and you have your answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for this annoyingly lengthy answer, which is probably way too detailed. I do wonder, though, if there are well-written tutorials on this topic for people who've never done type inference before.

Comment: This answer is very useful for those who are newbies to Haskell, like me, thanks!!

Comment: Another question related to the original:

If I evaluate take 5 (lolo (uncurry (==)) 1) in GHCi I get the result [1,1,1,1,1], but when I evaluate manually I get a different result.

I start evaluating lolo (uncurry (==)) = \x -> ys where ys = [x] ++ filter (== x) ys

Then I evaluate (lolo (uncurry (==))) 1 = (\x -> ys where ys = [x] ++ filter (== x) ys) 1 = (ys where ys = [1] ++ filter (== 1) ys)

If I invoke the above with ys = [1,2,3,4,5,6] then I get: [1] ++ filter (==1) [1,2,3,4,5,6] which result is [1, 1] so if I apply take 5 to the result I get [1, 1]. 

Any help?

Comment: The problem is that you 'invoke' with `ys`, which doesn't make sense. Not only is it weird (where does this `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` suddenly come from?), it also contradicts your definition of `lolo` or `fun` or whatever you called it (`ys` is a local binding, not a parameter to a function).

Comment: First to clarify lolo = fun, was a mistake to rename to lolo.

Ok, I undertand lolo (uncurry (==)) 1 doesn't have input parameters, and the output is [a], but then I don't understand why (ys where ys = [1] ++ filter (== 1) ys) = [1,1,1,1...]

Can you explain me?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

We can derive types in Haskell in a more or less mechanical manner, using the general scheme of

```
foo      x =  y                              -- is the same as
foo   = \x -> y                              -- so the types are
foo   :: a -> b          , x :: a , y :: b   -- so that
foo      x :: b
```

which means that e.g.

```
f    x    y    z :: d    , x :: a , y :: b, z :: c
```

entails

```
f    x    y :: c -> d
f    x :: b -> c -> d
f :: a -> b -> c -> d
```

etc. With these simple tricks type derivation will become trivial for you. Here, with

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]  
curry  :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
(++)   :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

we simply write down the stuff carefully lined up, processing it in a *top-down* manner, consistently renaming and substituting  the type variables, and recording the type equivalences on the side:

```
fun    g    x = ys   where   ys = [x] ++ filter (curry g x) ys 
fun    g    x :: c              , ys :: c
fun    g :: b -> c              , x  :: b 
fun :: a -> b -> c              , g  :: a
```

```
ys = [x] ++ filter (curry g x) ys
c  ~  c

(++)    [x]     (filter (curry g x) ys) :: c    
(++) :: [a1] -> [a1]                    -> [a1]   
-----------------------------------------------
(++) :: [b]  -> [b]                     -> [b]    , a1 ~ b , c ~ [b]

filter    (curry g x )     ys  :: [b] 
filter :: (a2 -> Bool) -> [a2] -> [a2]            , a2 ~ b
--------------------------------------
filter :: (b  -> Bool) -> [b]  -> [b]

curry     g                   x  :: b -> Bool
curry :: ((a3, b) -> c3  ) -> a3 -> b -> c3       , c3 ~ Bool , a3 ~ b
-------------------------------------------
curry :: ((b , b) -> Bool) -> b  -> b -> Bool     , a ~ ((b,b) -> Bool)
```

so we have that **`a ~ ((b,b) -> Bool)`** and **`c ~ [b]`**, and thus

```
fun :: a               -> b ->  c
fun :: ((b,b) -> Bool) -> b -> [b]
```

which is the same as `((a,a) -> Bool) -> a -> [a]`, up to a consistent renaming of type variables.