# Manual derivation of the type for `f1 x xs = (filter . (<)) x xs`

Tags: haskell, types, ghci, unification

I want to manually derive the type of:

`f1 x xs = (filter . (<)) x xs`

First time we see `x`, so:

```
x :: t1
```

Then `(<)` has this type:

```
(<) :: Ord a1 => a1 -> a1 -> Bool
```

We can only say `(< x)` if the following types can be unified:

```
t1  ~  a1
```

Then

```
x :: a1
```

So

```
(<x) :: Ord a1 => a1 -> Bool
```

Filter has this type

```
filter :: (a2 -> Bool) -> [a2] -> [a2]
```

First time to see xs, so:

```
xs :: t2
```

We can only say `(filter . (<)) x xs` if the following types can be unified:

```
a1 -> Bool ~ a2 -> Bool
t2  ~ [a2]
```

So I get that `f1 :: (a2 -> Bool) -> [a2] -> [a2]`, the same type as `filter`, when the correct type is `Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]` (asking GHCi).

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constraint

```
a1 -> Bool ~ a2 -> Bool
```

can be broken down to

```
a1 ~ a2
```

and the obviously true

```
Bool ~ Bool
```

So you have `a1 ~ a2`. You already know that `x` is `a1`, `xs` is `[a2]` and, thanks to `filter`, the result type is `[a2]`. Therefore, you end up with:

```
f1 :: Ord a2 => a2 -> [a2] -> [a2]
```

(Don't forget the class constraint `a1` got from `(<)`.)

Answer (score 3):

We can process given expressions in a top-down manner. This way there's no need to guess what goes where, the derivation happens purely mechanically, with minimal room for error:

```
f1    x   xs = (filter . (<)) x xs
f1    x   xs :: c                        (filter . (<)) x xs :: c
f1    x :: b -> c                        xs :: b
f1 :: a -> b -> c                        x  :: a 

(filter .  (<)) x      xs  :: c
filter    ((<)  x)  ::  b  -> c          c ~ [d] , b ~ [d]
filter :: (d->Bool) -> [d] -> [d]        (<) x :: d -> Bool

(<) :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> Bool
(<)               x :: d -> Bool         a ~ d , (Ord a)

f1  :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Another way to tackle this is to notice that *eta reduction* can be performed there in the definition of `f1`:

```
f1    x   xs = (filter . (<)) x xs
f1           = (.) filter (<)

(.) :: (   b      ->     c     ) -> (           a ->   b      ) -> (a->c)
(.)             filter                           (<)            ::   t1
(.) :: ((d->Bool) -> ([d]->[d])) -> ((Ord a) => a -> (a->Bool)) ->   t1

        b ~ d -> Bool , c ~ [d] -> [d] , t1 ~ a -> c , (Ord a)
        b ~ a -> Bool
        -------------
            d ~ a

f1 :: t1 ~ (Ord a) => a -> c 
         ~ (Ord a) => a -> [d] -> [d]
         ~ (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Of course we use the right associativity of arrows in types: `a -> b -> c` is actually `a -> (b -> c)`.

We also use [a general scheme for type derivations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23316814/849891)

```
f    x    y    z :: d
f    x    y :: c -> d      , z :: c
f    x :: b -> c -> d      , y :: b
f :: a -> b -> c -> d      , x :: a
```