# How to give a more general type to these two functions that have identical definitions?

Tags: haskell, types

Is it possible to somehow make the following code snippets more generic, we basically have 2 functions with identical code, the only difference being the function definition, is it possible to somehow abstract this away

```
unsafeListHandling :: [a] -> ([a] -> a) -> Maybe a
unsafeListHandling xs fx = if null xs then Nothing else Just $ fx xs

unsafeListHandling2 :: [a] -> ([a] -> [a]) -> Maybe [a]
unsafeListHandling2 xs fx = if null xs then Nothing else Just $ fx xs
```

Comment: Just remove the type signature and ask ghci for the inferred type.

Comment: that's one way but would it be possible to make the function definition more generic? I m in search of a technique rather then any solution

Comment: If you don't use language extensions, Haskell will infer the most general type. (There are a few exceptions, e.g. I don't think it can infer polymorphic recursion.)

Comment: @MrX: Put another way, melpomene is saying that "asking GHCi" *is* a technique :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The systematic way of doing that is covered in answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23329230/2751851). In many cases, though, a careful look at what we do know about the type signature is all we need to figure it out.

> ```
> unsafeListHandling  :: [a] -> ([a] ->  a ) -> Maybe  a
> unsafeListHandling2 :: [a] -> ([a] -> [a]) -> Maybe [a]
> ```

Things we know about the generalised `unsafeListHandling`:

- Its first argument should be a list of arbitrary type (let's take that as a requirement you have imposed).
- It should take a function on lists of that type as its second argument.
- It should produce a `Maybe` that matches the result type of the second argument.
- It should be possible to specialise the result type of the second argument to either the (list) type of the first argument or to its corresponding element type (that covers the difference between your two signatures).

If we write that down as a type signature, we get:

```
unsafeListHandling :: [a] -> ([a] -> b) -> Maybe b
```

With `a` being arbitrary and `b` being such that both `b ~ [a]` and `b ~ a` are valid specialisations. If we take `b` as literally just a free and unconstrained type variable, we can see that nothing stops us from specialising it to either `[a]` or `a`; that being so, the general type signature indeed is:

```
unsafeListHandling :: [a] -> ([a] -> b) -> Maybe b
unsafeListHandling xs fx = if null xs then Nothing else Just $ fx xs
```

If we follow melpomene's suggestion and ask GHCi the type of your function without adding any signatures...

```
GHCi> :t \xs fx -> if null xs then Nothing else Just $ fx xs
\xs fx -> if null xs then Nothing else Just $ fx xs
  :: Foldable t => t a -> (t a -> a1) -> Maybe a1
```

... we get just that, except for the unconcerning generalisation of `[a]` to `Foldable t => t a`, which happens because the type of `null` is `Foldable t => t a -> Bool`. By the way, if you are using GHC 8, you can enable the `TypeApplications` extension and use it as a convenient way to specialise `null` for your type tetris purposes:

```
GHCi> :set -XTypeApplications
GHCi> :t \xs fx -> if null @[] xs then Nothing else Just $ fx xs
\xs fx -> if null @[] xs then Nothing else Just $ fx xs
  :: [a] -> ([a] -> a1) -> Maybe a1
```

To wrap things up, a demonstration that the generalised function actually does what you want:

```
GHCi> (\xs fx -> if null @[] xs then Nothing else Just $ fx xs) [1..7] head
Just 1
GHCi> (\xs fx -> if null @[] xs then Nothing else Just $ fx xs) [1..7] tail
Just [2,3,4,5,6,7]
```