# Finding the type of a composition function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, function-definition

Let's say I have the following function in Haskell:

`compose2 = (.) . (.)`

How would I go about finding the type of this function? Because of the multiple compositions I get stuck trying to determine what the type of this function would be.

I know I can use `:t compose2` to get the type. However, I want to know how to do it without the aid of a computer. What steps should I take to find the type?

Comment: closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701011/how-to-manually-infer-the-type-of

Comment: for an answer to "how to go about deriving type of *a* function in general" see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14558244/849891) or browse through e.g. [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+mechanically)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I wasn't able to find a similar post myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might help if we fist give the composition functions a more unique identifier, for example:

```
compose2 = (.)₂ .₁ (.)₃
```

that way it is easier to refer to some function. We can also convert this to a more canonical form, like:

```
compose2 = ((.)₁ (.)₂) (.)₃
```

so now we can start deriving the function type. We know that `(.)` has type [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.), or more canonical `(.) :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))`. Since the type variables are not "global", we thus can give the tree functions different names for the type variables:

```
(.)₁ :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))
(.)₂ :: (e -> f) -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))
(.)₃ :: (h -> i) -> ((g -> h) -> (g -> i))
```

so now that we have given the different composition functions a signature, we can start deriving the types.

We know that `(.)₂` is the parameter of a function application with `(.)₁`, so that means that the type of the parameter `(b -> c)` is the same as the type `(e -> f) -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))`, and therefore that `b ~ (e -> f)`, and `c ~ ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))`.

We furthermore know that the type of the "second" parameter of `(.)₁` is the same as the type of `(.)₃`, so `(a -> b) ~ ((h -> i) -> ((g -> h) -> (g -> i)))`, and therefore `a ~ (h -> i)`, and `b ~ ((g -> h) -> (g -> i))`, therefore the "return type" of `(.)₁`, which is `(a -> c)` can thus be specialized to:

```
((.)₁ (.)₂) (.)₃ :: a -> c
```

and since `a ~ (h -> i)`, and `c ~ (d -> e) -> (d -> f)`:

```
((.)₁ (.)₂) (.)₃ :: (h -> i) -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))
```

we know that `b` is equivalent to both `b ~ (e -> f)` and `b ~ ((g -> h) -> (g -> i))`, so that means that `e ~ (g -> h)`, and `f ~ (g -> i)`, we thus can specialize the signature further to:

```
((.)₁ (.)₂) (.)₃ :: (h -> i) -> ((d -> (g -> h)) -> (d -> (g -> i)))
```

which is a more verbose form of:

```
(.)₂ .₁ (.)₃ :: (h -> i) -> (d -> g -> h) -> d -> g -> i
```

If we automatically derive the type, we obtain:

```
Prelude> :t (.) . (.)
(.) . (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a1 -> a -> b) -> a1 -> a -> c
```

If we thus replace `b` with `h`, `c` with `i`, `a1` with `d` and `a` with `g`, we obtain the same type.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive answer! I am able to get the type myself now :)