# Reasoning about types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, function-composition, hindley-milner

Chapter 16  of "Haskell Programming from First Principles" on page 995 has an exercise to manually work out how `(fmap . fmap)` typechecks. It suggests substituting the type of each `fmap` for the function types in the type of the composition operator:

T1 `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`

T2 `fmap :: Functor f => (m -> n) -> f m -> f n`

T3 `fmap :: Functor g => (x -> y) -> g x -> g y`

By (attempting to) substitute T2 and T3 into T1, I arrived at the following:

T4: `((m -> n) -> f m -> f n) -> ((x -> y) -> g x -> g y) -> a -> c`

Further, it suggests checking the type of `(fmap . fmap)` to see what the end type should look like.

T5: `(fmap . fmap) :: (Functor f1, Functor f2) => (a -> b) -> f1 (f2 a) -> f1 (f2 b)`

I'm having trouble understanding what I should be doing here. Could any knowledgeable haskellers help get me started, or maybe provide examples of similar exercises that show how to work out types by hand?

Comment: I give a shortened derivation at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34701189/849891), see if it helps.

Comment: You substituted for `a` and `c` in some places, but not others. You have to do it everywhere to get the right type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We proceed step by careful step:

```
--- fmap . fmap  =  (.) fmap fmap
--- Functor f, g, ... => ..... 

(.)      :: (   b     ->      c    ) -> (a ->  b ) -> a ->     c
    fmap ::  (d -> e) -> f d -> f e
             --------    ----------
(.) fmap ::                             (a ->d->e) -> a -> f d -> f e
                                             ----          ----------
-- then,

(.) fmap      :: (   a     ->  d  ->  e ) -> a   -> f   d   -> f   e
         fmap ::  (b -> c) -> g b -> g c
                  --------    ---    ---
(.) fmap fmap ::                          (b->c) -> f (g b) -> f (g c)
                                          ------      -----      -----
```

It is important to consistently rename all the type variables on each separate use of a type, to avoid conflation.

We use the fact that the arrows associate on the right,

```
 A -> B -> C   ~   A -> (B -> C)
```

and the type inference rule is

```
   f   :: A -> B
     x :: C
   --------------
   f x ::      B    ,  A ~ C
```

`(f :: A -> B) (x :: C) :: B` under the equivalence / unification of types `A ~ C` and all that it entails.