# Haskell dot operator with sort and (++)

Tags: haskell, dot-operator

I am learning haskell at the moment and trying to figure out all the rules of prefix, infix, precedence, etc.

While trying to implement a function which appends two lists and sorts them I started with:

```
appendAndSort :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
appendAndSort = sort . (++)
```

which does no compile.

Following:

```
appendAndSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
appendAndSort = (sort .) . (++)
```

on the other hand does work.

Why do I have to add a second dot at sort and parentheses around it?

Comment: "does work" Sure? You cannot sort an arbitrary list, you need an `Ord a` constraint or something.

Comment: Anyway, do you understand the meaning of notation like `(a +)` or `(2 *)`? `(sort .)` is the same sort of things. Type `:t (sort .)` at ghci prompt, can you make sense of what it prints?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. You are right I forgot the constraint `Ord a`.
The tipp with printing the type is helping.

Comment: "Why do I have to add a second dot" because `(++)` is a binary function (expects two arguments).

Comment: viewed differently, you want to sort the result "contained" inside `(++)` which is a <s> *binary* function</s> ahem a *doubly-nested* functor. thus you need to use the [*doubly nested* `fmap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34701189/849891) i.e. `appendAndSort = fmap (fmap sort) (++)` which happens to be the same as `(.) ((.) sort) (++)` or with [operator section syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+%22laws+of+operator+sections%22) `(.) (sort .) (++) = ((sort .) . (++))` (outer parens optional, in the last one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `(f . g) x` means `f (g x)`.

Coherently, `(f . g) x y` means `f (g x) y`.

Note how `y` is passed as a second parameter to `f`, not to `g`. The result is *not* `f (g x y)`.

In your case, `(sort . (++)) x y` would mean `sort ((++) x) y`, which would call `sort` with first argument `(++) x` (the function which prepends the list `x` to its list argument), and with second argument `y`. Alas, this is ill-typed since `sort` only takes one argument.

Consequently, this is also invalid

```
appendAndSort x y = (sort . (++)) x y
```

hence so is this

```
appendAndSort = sort . (++)
```

---

By contrast, `((f .) . g) x y` does work as expected. Let's compute:

```
((f .) . g) x y
=  -- same reasoning as above, y is passed to (f.), not g
(f .) (g x) y
=  -- application associates on the left
((f .) (g x)) y
=  -- definition of `(f.)`
(f . (g x)) y
= -- definition of .
f ((g x) y)
=  -- application associates on the left
f (g x y)
```

So this really makes `y` to be passed to `g` (and not `f`).

In my opinion the "idiom" `(f .) . g` isn't worth using. The pointful `\x y -> f (g x y)` is much simpler to read, and not terribly longer.

---

If you really want, you can define a custom composition operator to handle the two-argument case.

```
(.:) f g = \x y -> f (g x y)
```

Then, you can write

```
appendAndSort = sort .: (++)
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with a version that uses explicit parameters.

```
appendAndSort x y = sort (x ++ y)
```

Writing `++` as a prefix function rather than an operator yields

```
appendAndSort x y = sort ((++) x y)
```

Knowing that `(f . g) x == f (g x)`, we can identify `f == sort` and `g == (++) x` to get

```
appendAndSort x y = (sort . (++) x) y
```

which lets us drop `y` as an explicit parameter via [eta conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion):

```
appendAndSort x = sort . (++) x
```

The next step is to repeat the process above, this time with `(.)` as the top most operator to write as a prefix function,

```
appendAndSort x = (.) sort ((++) x)
```

then apply the definition of `.` again with `f == (.) sort` and `g == (++)`:

```
appendAndSort x = (((.) sort) . (++)) x
```

and eliminate `x` via eta conversion

```
appendAndSort = ((.) sort) . (++)
```

The last step is to write `(.) sort` as an operator section, and we're done with our derivation.

```
appendAndSort = (sort .) . (++)
```