# Type of the Haskell expression takeWhile even

Tags: haskell, types

If anyone can help me out with clearing this question?

The Standard Prelude function takeWhile has type `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`

Write down the type of the Haskell expression `takeWhile even`
The function `even` is defined as:

```
even x = x `mod` 2 == 0
```

Would this be considered right?

```
takeWhile:: Num a => (a->Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: No. `takeWhile even` is an expression whose value is a function with only **one** argument.  You have to find the type of `takeWhile even :: ?`.

Comment: Hint: you need the type signature of `even` and then overlay it with the type signature of `takeWhile`.

Comment: So something like takeWhile even :: [Int]->[Int]

Comment: `[Int]->[Int]` is indeed a possible instantiation of `takeWhile even`, but it's not the most general one.

Comment: Then would this be considered correct takeWhile even :: (Num a) => [a]->[a]

Comment: Well, almost. The signature is right, but the `Num` constraint is not strong enough. — You're aware that GHCi `:t` will easily show you the type (be it declared or inferred) of any expression, right?

Comment: GHCi says `even :: Integral a => a -> Bool`

Comment: check out this [general scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23316814/849891) for  dealing with types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To derive the type signature of `takeWhile even` you need to first take a look at the type signature for `takeWhile` and `even`. According to GHCi, the type signatures for those functions are the following.

```
takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]

even :: Integral a => a -> Bool
```

In the case of `takeWhile even`, `takeWhile` takes in a function of type `(a -> Bool)`, thus a function that takes in some value of type `a` and returns a `Bool`.

The `even` function takes in an `Integral` value and returns a `Bool` value, so it can be passed in as the first argument to `takeWhile`. Since the `Integral` typeclass is implemented by several different types such as `Int` and `Integer`, you can pass in a value of any such type that implements the `Integer` typeclass.

You will want to notice that in `takeWhile`, the `a` in `(a -> Bool)` is not bound to any typeclass, however in `even` the corresponding `a` is bound to the `Integral` typeclass. In this case, this causes the resulting expression to bind the `a` in the `takeWhile` type signature to `Integral`. For example, you could imagine `takeWhile` to have the following type signature in this case:

```
takeWhile :: Integral a => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Also, since the first argument of `takeWhile` is filled by `even`, the type signature of the resulting expression does not have the `(a -> Bool)` term.

Thus, you are left with the following type signature for `takeWhile even`. Therefore `takeWhile even` takes in a list of `Integral` values and returns a list of `Integral` values of the same type.

```
takeWhile even :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
```

If you want to confirm this using GHCi, you can run the following command to get the type signature of the expression:

```
:t takeWhile even
```

Comment: "Bound to" usually means something else. Maybe use "constrained by"? I'm not really sure how to express that occasionally in English.

Comment: @dfeuer You are right, "constrained by" would probably be more accurate in this case.

Comment: Oh boy, I just saw that my comment about wording had an auto-correct error. I meant *accurately*, not *occasionally*.